# webDriver.quit() gives exception without a message

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

Sometimes webDriver.quit() method gives exception without a message. But it closes the browser succesfully. It only happens on grid, I couldn't reproduce this in local machine. It may related to parallel execution, I don't know. Exception seems random, which is makes me crazy not to find out.

At the end of the test, my code block is;

```
public void close() {
    try {
        webDriver.quit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Exception on closing webdriver", ex);
    }
}
```

And the error log is:

```
2016-04-17 20:18:02,169 ERROR [pool-1-thread-1] models.Browser - Exception on ?closing webdriver
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'taylanderinbay.local', ip: '172.20.0.196', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.4', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=45.0.2, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=e64115cd-ba83-4e01-89b8-e5b16e7a4e0f, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: e64115cd-ba83-4e01-89b8-e5b16e7a4e0f
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:701) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:526) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0.jar:?]
    at com.dmall.uat.models.Browser.close(Browser.java:228) [classes/:?]
    at com.dmall.uat.models.users.Visitor.closeBrowser(Visitor.java:214) [classes/:?]
    at com.dmall.uat.test.TestContext.closeBrowsers(TestContext.java:48) [classes/:?]
    at com.dmall.uat.test.StopOrCloseFixtures$1.evaluate(StopOrCloseFixtures.java:30) [classes/:?]
    at com.dmall.uat.test.FreeUser$1.evaluate(FreeUser.java:23) [classes/:?]
    at com.dmall.uat.test.FreeAccount$1.evaluate(FreeAccount.java:23) [classes/:?]
    at com.dmall.uat.test.FailedTestRetry$1.evaluate(FailedTestRetry.java:29) [classes/:?]
    at com.dmall.uat.test.TestContextInitializer$1.evaluate(TestContextInitializer.java:24) [classes/:?]
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.pc.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:387) [surefire-junit47-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_77]
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been taken
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'taylanderinbay.local', ip: '172.20.0.196', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.4', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:138) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0.jar:?]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils$ProcessWaiter.run(ProcessUtils.java:164) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
```

I really appreciate any help or suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Could be a driver compatibility issue: seems you are using firefox 45, and as I see from changelog, it's not supported by selenium 2.53 (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG)

Comment: Never thought about that, but it may be the reason. I'll try after downgrading

Comment: No. Still gives the same exception after downgrade to 44

Comment: Must be some sort of windows + java bug then (`Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor` looks like something far beyond selenium...) Could be legitimate even, so you could ignore it: `catch (Exception ex) { if(ex instanceof InterruptedException && Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) return;
        logger.error("Exception on closing webdriver", ex);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sometimes when you quit the driver you are interrupting taking a screenshot.  Maybe finishing some IO.

Do you get the screenshots you expect when running on the grid?
Try setting takesScreenshot=false in your driver capabilities and see if it continues to happen.

Comment: I take screenshots only when there is an exception or assertion error. It tries to do that because of webdriver exception here. But it cannot take it of course because webdriver.quit actually closes browser as I wanted.

But I'll check with closing the screenshot and write here.